# Issue on keeping Mega Menu visible when hover (Mega Menu outside Main Menu)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple mega menu and I am trying to keep the submenu (outside a menu, not inside) visible if a user hover overs it or hover over the menu item. 
However, when I get off the hover menu item the submenu will hide. I try to use 2 hover function for both menu item and the submenu outside the menu but no luck, the submenu still slideUp first, then slideDown before.

The eg as demonstrated above has the following code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var $ = jQuery;
  var _nav = $(".menu-wrapper li");
  var _nav_offset = _nav.offset();
  var _nav_height = _nav.outerHeight();
  var wST = $(window).scrollTop();

  $('#menu-dropdown').css({
    'top': _nav_offset.top - wST + _nav_height
  })

  $(".menu-wrapper li").hover(function() {
    $('#menu-dropdown').slideDown();
  }, function() {
    $('#menu-dropdown').slideUp();
  })

  $('#menu-dropdown').hover(function() {
    $('#menu-dropdown').slideDown();
  }, function() {
    $('#menu-dropdown').slideUp();
  })
})
```

```css
#menu {
 position:relative;
 padding-top:10px;
 text-align:center;
}
#menu ul {
 display:block;
 background:#f5f5f5;
 line-height:60px;
}
#menu .menu-wrapper .menu-item {
 display:inline-block;
 padding:5px 20px;
 color:#111;
}
#menu-dropdown {
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
 z-index:999;
 display:none;
}
.dropdown-content {
 background:#333;
 color:#fff;
 padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <ul class="menu-wrapper">
    <li class="menu-item">Home</li>
    <li class="menu-item">About</li>
    <li class="menu-item">Contact</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="menu-dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p class="paragraph">Phoenix</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Aren't there any better way to do this?
Noted: I am looking for the answer that the submenu outside menu

Thanks

Comment: why is it necessary, that the sub menu is outside the main menu list? thanks to css, you could nest the ul for the menu and submenu and still separate the views

Comment: I'm creating an app that can replace the normal dropdown menu into a mega menu on a platform. And to do that, it is necessary, that the sub menu is outside the main menu list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution. You could Also add a timeout function within the `mouseenter/mouseleave` functions to prevent them from firing immediately.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      var $ = jQuery;
      var _nav = $(".menu-wrapper li");
      var _nav_offset = _nav.offset();
      var _nav_height = _nav.outerHeight();
      var wST = $(window).scrollTop();

      $('#menu-dropdown').css({
        'top': _nav_offset.top - wST + _nav_height
      })

      $(".menu-wrapper li").mouseenter(function() {
          $('#menu-dropdown').stop().slideDown();
      });
      
      $(".menu-wrapper li, #menu-dropdown").mouseleave(function() {
        if(!$('#menu-dropdown').is(':hover')){
          $('#menu-dropdown').slideUp();
        };
      });
});
```

```css
#menu {
     position:relative;
     padding-top:10px;
     text-align:center;
    }
    #menu ul {
     display:block;
     background:#f5f5f5;
     line-height:60px;
    }
    #menu .menu-wrapper .menu-item {
     display:inline-block;
     padding:5px 20px;
     color:#111;
    }
    #menu-dropdown {
     position:fixed;
     top:0;
     left:0;
     width:100%;
     height:auto;
     z-index:999;
     display:none;
    }
    .dropdown-content {
     background:#333;
     color:#fff;
     padding:20px;
    }
    #test{
    margin-top:100px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div id="menu">
      <ul class="menu-wrapper">
        <li class="menu-item">Home</li>
        <li class="menu-item">About</li>
        <li class="menu-item">Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="menu-dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <p class="paragraph">Phoenix</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Alternatively you could just add `.stop()` before each action like this:

```
  $(".menu-wrapper li").hover(function() {
    $('#menu-dropdown').stop().slideDown();
  }, function() {
    $('#menu-dropdown').stop().slideUp();
  })

  $('#menu-dropdown').hover(function() {
    $('#menu-dropdown').stop().slideDown();
  }, function() {
    $('#menu-dropdown').stop().slideUp();
  })
```

This can, however, give a slightly janky animation (in my opinion at leaast).